# Customize Menu in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, menu

I want to remove some of the menu items and also want to disable menu on click of the button on some screens of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `addMenuItem`  and `removeMenuItem(menuitem)` to add and remove `menuitems` in blackberry.

Refer blackberry library links [addMenuItem()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#addMenuItem%28net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem%29) and [MenuItem Class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html)